# Is there a list of wizard spells by level by school?

Tags: spells, dnd-5e

I want to try making a wizard for my next character but noticed that the spell lists are poorly sorted when choosing an arcane tradition. After a quick [google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=d%26d%205th%20wizard%20spell%20list%20by%20school) turned up nothing useful I thought I would turn here.

Does anyone have a list of wizard spells by level by school?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the recent [Sage Advice Rules Roundup](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/sage-advice-june2015) includes an [index of spells](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DnD_SpellLists_1.0.pdf) sorted alphabetically, by class, by level, and by school (starting on page 7).

Answer (score 5):

## [D&D Beyond's Spell Index](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells)

D&D Beyond is an offically licensed digital resource for 5e, and their spell section allows for filtering by class, school, level, as well as a myriad of other properties for the spells. The SRD spells are availible directly through their site, but non-SRD content will require a purchase (still very useful as an index).

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a great spell](http://mouseferatu.com/index.php/news/august-8-2014-a-special-gift-for-my-fellow-dd-fans/) sorter excel sheet that someone created. It allows you to sort and filter spells by name, level, school, class, and sub class.

[Click here for a direct download of the Spell Sorter (v1.3).](http://mouseferatu.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Aris-5E-Spell-Sorter-v1.3.xls)

Comment: Neither of the two links work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great spell list over at [donjon.bin.sh](http://donjon.bin.sh/5e/spells/) that allows you to show spells by class, school, as well as a bunch of other criteria.