# Where can I find the old post of "A Compilation of Useful Spell Lists" from the now deleted WoTC Forums?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I see that the WOTC forums are closed.  I also see in Google, that it had an amazing list of spells sorted by all sorts of topics.
I also see that EN world had a "save WOTC forum posts" in their forum but I can't find these lists posted there.

Does anyone know if these lists exist anywhere else or if they are gone as soon as the cache is no longer searchable?

This is the cached version of the page that is missing:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gPl9-zEVS70J:community.wizards.com/forum/player-help/threads/4139341+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=il

Comment: You may also be interested in [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/63881/6104) (for an official resource).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Someone has [reposted it on the EN World forums](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?468661-A-Compilation-of-Useful-Spell-Lists) or you can access [the Wayback Machine version](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919205508/http://community.wizards.com/forum/player-help/threads/4139341) which should last longer than Google's cache.

You could also just save the html page yourself (or copy out the information) so you always have a local copy.

Comment: Your ability to search their forums is much more impressive than mine. Thanks. Can you explain your process?

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli Why not just favorite the question?

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli Does the mobile version let you favorite the question? I didn't think it did.

Comment: @GMNoob I actually used google, since it lets you search a specific site. Typing this into google returns the page as the first result `site:enworld.org A Compilation of Useful Spell Lists`

Answer (score 1):

Crawford put a link to it on his October 2015 Sage Advice:
http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-references-october-2015

Comment: This doesn't actually have what I was looking for. But thanks.

Comment: @GMNoob as I tried to mention earlier, if you are looking for a 5E list of spells you can sort by various factors, perhaps http://donjon.bin.sh/5e/spells/ might help.

Comment: @Airatome as I responded, it doesn't have the filters that I want to sort by. Namely, "Does the spell make use of the casting stat"